# What is the equivalent of "(byte)" in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, type-conversion

What is the equivalent of `(byte)` in VB.NET:

#### C#:

```
uint value = 1161;
byte data = (byte)value;
```

data = 137

#### VB.NET:

```
  Dim value As UInteger = 1161
  Dim data1 As Byte = CType(value, Byte)
  Dim data2 As Byte = CByte(value)
```

Exception: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

How can I achieve the same result as in C#?

Comment: A Byte may store up 255 (unsigned), C# silently convert the value, but VB seems not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, C# does not check for integer overflows, but VB.NET does.

You get the same exception in C# if you e.g. wrap your code in a `checked` block:

```
checked
{
    uint value = 1161;
    byte data = (byte)value;
}
```

---

In your VB.NET project properties, enable *Configuration Properties* => *Optimizations* => *Remove Integer Overflow Checks*, and your VB.NET code will work exactly like your C# code.

Integer overflow checks are then disabled for your entire project, but that's usually not a problem.

Comment: Proposing a setting change that disables *all* overflow checking just to make one statement work is not good advice.

Comment: Disabling all overflow checking is rarely a proplem at all (in fact, I never encountered such a situation). You probably want to disable it anyway if you override `GetHashCode()`.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus You have no idea whether or not overflow checking is depended on elsewhere in the project.  Changing this setting at the start of a project when there is no existing code would be fine, but on a large developed project you'd need to re-test everything if you did this.

Answer (score 6):

Try first chopping the most significant bytes off the number, then converting it to Byte:

```
Dim value As UInteger = 1161 
Dim data1 As Byte = CType(value And 255, Byte)
Dim data2 As Byte = CByte(value And 255)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get just the most significant byte, you can do the rather hackalicious

```
Dim data1 = BitConvertor.GetBytes(value)(0)
```

It's explicit, and you wouldn't need to disable overflow checking.