# converting from c# to vb.net byte

Tags: c#, vb.net, byte

i had tried to convert c# code to vb.net code.

the c# code is :

```
int m = 300;
byte h = (byte)m;
```

my vb code is :

```
dim m as integer = 300
dim h as byte = cbyte(m)
```

the error is:

> Message=Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

the expected value is:

```
 h value is 44 byte.
```

Comment: dim h as byte = cbyte(300).... Shouldn't it be  dim h as byte = cbyte(m)

Comment: Downcasting a numeric integer type like `int32` to a smaller integer type like `byte` carries the risk of an overflow. The .NET runtime is trying to be helpful and letting you know this causes an error, and you will lose data.

It looks like you are doing this in a runtime that is configured to perform checked arithmetic, meaning that it will detect these errors.

You can avoid the error by using the `unchecked` keyword:
```
unchecked
{
 int i = 300;
 byte b = (byte)i;
 b.Dump();
}
```

Comment: @Kevin Gosse, I don't think that solves the question. That's a bad duplicate.

Comment: @n234 the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284223/what-is-the-equivalent-of-byte-in-vb-net) is *exactly the same* (short of picking different number to start). There is no way it is not a duplicate. You indeed free to edit this question to clarify why it is different so it can be potentially re-opened.

Comment: It's actually the reverse of the question, since this guy wants it to overflow without an exception!

Comment: i get the answer from another question , Dim h = BitConvertor.GetBytes(m)(0)

Answer (score 0):

Your size cannot be more than 255

> Byte.MinValue (0) through Byte.MaxValue (255) (unsigned); fractional parts are rounded.1
>
> Starting with Visual Basic 15.8, Visual Basic optimizes the performance of floating-point to byte conversion with the CByte function; see the Remarks section for more information. See the CInt Example section for an example.